# Yup schema generator for form array and nested form groups using Formik, Material-UI - React

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui, formik, yup

I have an yup schema generator for generating yup schema which is working fine but fails when it comes to handling Form Arrays and Nested Form Groups.

Yup Schema Generator

```
const createYupSchema = (schema, config)=> {
  if (config.validation) {
    const { validationType, validations = [] } = config.validation;
    if (!yup[validationType]) {
      return schema;
    }
    let validator = yup[validationType]();
    validations.forEach((validation) => {
    const { params, type } = validation;
    if (!validator[type]) {
      return;
    }
    validator = validator[type](...params);
  });
   schema[config.props.name] = validator;
  }
 return schema;
}
```

schema of my form structure

```
"addressType":{
  "props":{
    "name":"addressType",
    "label":"Address type:",
    "type":"radio"
   },
  "value":"workPlace",
  "validation":{
    "validationType":"string",
    "validations":[
      {
        "type":"required",
        "params":[
           "Address is required"
        ]
      }
    ]
   }
 },
"students":{
  "props":{
    "name":"students"
  },
  "fields":{
    "studentName":{
     "name":"studentName",
     "type":"text",
     "label":"student name"
    },
  "age":{
     "name":"age",
     "type":"number",
     "label":"Age"
    }
 },
"validation":{
  "name":"students",
  "validationType":"array",
  "validations":[
     {
        "studentName":{
           "validations":[
              "type":"required",
              "params":[
                 "StudentName is required"
              ]
           ]
        }
     }
  ]
 }
}
```

How can I achieve yup schema dynamically for Formik Array and nested Form Groups.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You should use a recurring call to make it work for array and object.

```
if (validation.type === 'array' || validation.type === 'object') {
 const innerSchema = createYupSchema({}, {
    props: { name: 'key' },
    validations: validation.validations
 });
 validator = yup.array().of(
    yup.object().shape(innerSchema[key])
 );
}
```

Comment: This might not work, but I just wanted to give you the basics how the code will look like.
Also, you may need to change the data structure to make it simple.